# Directive issue in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a dropdown that works just fine. If user selects an option and then presses the **"Delete"** Or **"Backspace"** button from keyboard the value from the dropdown will clear (**this works great**). However, I'm trying to create a **Directive** that will do the same thing, but I can't get it to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to properly create this directive?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's my code:

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-automation-osjiwr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
onKeyUp(evt){
   if(evt.keyCode === 8){
     this.isShowClear = false;
     let currentElementName = evt.currentTarget.getAttribute('name');
     this.myForm.controls[currentElementName].patchValue('');
 }
}

onChange(){
this.isShowClear = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a code of directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[customDropDown]'
})
export class CustomDropDownDirective {

  @Output() updateProperty: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control : NgControl) { }

    @HostListener('keyup',['$event'])onkeyup(event:any){
    if(event.keyCode === 8){
       let currentElementName = this.el.nativeElement.value;
      this.control.control.setValue('');
      this.updateProperty.emit(false);
    }
  }
}
```

here is a link of [LIVE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-automation-tapmj2) i just update your example. and one more thing, which is you forgot to include your directive in `app.component.ts` that's why he was not working in demo.

Comment: Also add `event.keyCode === 46` which is for delete key.

Comment: @SaddamPojee yes you are right I forgot to mention this keyCode, because I fork his example, so that's why I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do use **keypress** thing which will help you to catch event on **keypress**. It can be done like this

```
@HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) { 
    this.key = event.key;

    // inside this you can catch your key code
    // then check is it backspace or delete keycode 
    // if it is then remove data from selector with help of NgControl.
  }
```

Don't forget to import your NgControl from @angular/core.